# Why /V1/carts/mine/totals [GET] and /V1/carts/mine [GET] give 400 and 404 error after placed order in Magento-2.2.7 using Rest API?

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, http-error-404

I have one issue in Magento-2.2.7 API.After Placed order, This API /V1/carts/mine/totals [GET] and /V1/carts/mine [GET] give errors

> 400[Bad Request],404[Not Found] error.

Please guide me what is issue in this api .

Comment: Maybe once you created your order your cart is empty so you have no cart totals and an empty cart?

Comment: I agree but 400[Bad Request],404[Not Found] error is not a solution. It show any response instead of error. @zack6849